# Can't access children when adopting an element with SVG.js

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, svg.js

I'm trying to let the user manipulate an avatar, with svg.js in Ionic 3, by replacing parts of the avatar (i.e. g tags representing the face, arms, etc.).

I load the avatar svg as an object, select the svg tag and 'adopt' it with svg.js as in the code below, but I can't access any of the children.

`<object id="defaultGirl" type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/avatar/default-girl.svg" class=""></object>`

```
let a: any = document.getElementById("defaultAvatarObj")
let b: any = a.contentDocument
let c: any = b.querySelector('svg')
let d: any = SVG.adopt(c)
let e: any = d.children()
console.log(e) // displays *[initializer]* -- an array with an 'initializer' object, rather than the children
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You get back an array you say? And this array contains one element you say? Any chance, that this is the object you are searching for? Because svg.js wraps all elements in its own objects to add the methods. Check the node property to be sure

Comment: @Fuzzyma The element in the array is the defs element created by svg.js, but the rest of the children that I expect aren't there.

Comment: Take a look at the Dom inspector and verify that the querySelector selects the correct element and this element has indeed children - or create a codepen - that's actually the better solution

Comment: Yes, it's selecting the correct element.  I'm not sure how to create a codepen with an object reference because the file is on my computer.

Comment: When using an online svg resource like so: <object id="target" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg" onload=run()></object>    I get a cors problem. If you have any suggestions on how to use codepen effectively please let me know

Comment: Copy and paste the svg into the html area?

Comment: I think the problem arises when loading the svg with <object>.  Instead, I loaded my svgs with ajax (and later httpclient for angular) and had no problems transferring nodes between svg elements

Comment: That could be. It could be that svgs in object tags are somehow handled as shadow down and therefore not accessible. Why are you using object tags after all?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an svg which is loaded via object tag. The browser is loading the object and displaying it. Any implementation details are hidden.

Its the same as using an svg image with `<img>`.

When you need to alter the svg image, insert it into the dom. You can do that by requesting the file via ajax and insert it into the dom or directly include the svg code when the page is generated

Comment: You can access the svg contents inside an object! You need to call the contentDocument property. Then call one of the children of that document in order to get the actual <svg> contents. You might need to convert that child using innerHtml or something, but the svg data is there and accessible.

Comment: True that might work. However, you can only access svgs from the same origin and they are readOnly, too.